# how to open file whose name is stored in a variable in php

Tags: php

I have written a basic login form and registration form and stored them in database including the details of the individual I have also created an another row called filename whose name would be the entered username .php suppose if anyone enters John the filename would be john.php so that the person goes only to that specific file whenever he logged in but in login form I stored the filename in a specific variable and wanted to open when user gets logged in the code in login.php is

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$filename = $username.".php";
$errflag  = false;
if($username == '' and $password == '') {
 echo "you must enter username and password";
   $errflag = true;
}
if ($errflag == false) {
   SignIn($username,$password);
}
}
function SignIn($username,$password){
global $connection;
$search = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where username = 
:username AND password = :password");
$search->bindParam(':username',$username);
$search->bindParam(':password',$password);
$search->execute();
$count = $search->rowCount();
if($count> 0)
{

    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    header("Location : $filename");


}
else{
    echo "wrong email or password";
}
}
?>
```

I used header('Location : ') so that I can redirect to the file whose name stored in $filename I tried with header('location:'.$filename); and also header("location: $filename"); but both of those returns an error is there any way so that I can redirect to that filename stored in the variable thank you

Comment: `$filename` doesn't appear to be defined in the scope of your function. Try passing it in

Comment: thankyou robjingram it is the answer I made a mistake by forgetting it's declaration as global in function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one small mistake that you are doing.

please see this below code.

```
$filename = $username.".php"; // Write it here in the signIn function
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
header("Location : $filename");
```

Or just pass the `$filename` as a parameter in the function.

`SignIn($username,$password, $filename);`

Also, Add the `$filename` parameter in the function definition

```
function SignIn($username,$password, $filename){
   // Code goes here
}
```

Change the header location with below code.

```
header("Location : ".$filename);
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score -1):

Your variable $filename is a string, so your header will be something like:

```
header("Location:"John.php"")
```

,which is why header does no work, if the username is john. Also, you are trying to redirect the file to an unexisting file, that is, if a new user enters a name, such as Jason, then the server cannot redirect to your assumed Jason.php file, since you have not created it yet. What you should do is to create a front page file and you should use the posted information and display appropriate details. And next time, please make use of dots and commas.